# Using android square's picasso only for caching and decoding

Tags: android, picasso, square

I would like to use Picasso (https://github.com/square/picasso) for caching and bitmap decoding, the problem i'm having is that my request is for a url like for example : server.com/component/1 which gives me a proto file that i parse that contains some other information and a bytestring of the image that i decode to a bitmap.

Is there a way to use picasso for this even thought the request url is not just for an image or just use it for caching and decoding my bitmaps, I've tried using the class Target but it works only with a url of an image alone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, what can you do is just caching, `load` method has only 4 overrides for `Uri`, `String`, `Bitmap`, `int`. So when you will use `Bitmap` as a parameter, you will be able to cache your bitmap. Picasso was created only as an image loader, so I don't think that it has method that received all data from the server.